# How to debug client/server code in meteor-angular using Webstorm

Tags: babeljs, angular-meteor

I'm trying to configure my Webstorm(2016.1.1) to debug my meteor-angular project but with no success.

I set the environment as should so i can start a server from Webstorm but it does not stop on breakpoints.

I've searched all over the place but did not find how to configure it right.

What i've done so far:

1. Set up a file watcher for Babel (on Webstorm)
2. Set the project to use Ecmascript6 (Languages & Frameworks > Javascript) (on Webstorm)
3. Set up my project to run meteor (on Webstorm)
4. Added a `babel.json` file to the root of the project and inserted this line: 
   `{
   "sourceMaps": "both",
   "extensions": ["js"] 
   }`  [(tried it after reading this thread](https://github.com/pbastowski/angular-meteor-babel/issues/11)

But webstorm just won't hit the breakpoint(if i put the breakpoint inside the .meteor build it will stop but it is not the right way to do it)

What am i missing?
10x